# How to convert itunes music files in to a low bandwidth PCM for uploading

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-audio

i will like to convert itunes music files in to a low bandwidth PCM for uploading.

[How to convert m4a file to aac adts file in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292620/how-to-convert-m4a-file-to-aac-adts-file-in-xcode)

[Real-time converting the PCM buffer to AAC data for iOS using Remote IO and Audio Convert Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487722/real-time-converting-the-pcm-buffer-to-aac-data-for-ios-using-remote-io-and-audi)

[iOS: Create an MP3 on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145623/ios-create-an-mp3-on-device)

i saw a few threads but not too sure how do i go about it. Could anyone provide me a tutorial link please ?

any comment are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use ExtAudioFileConvert API from Apple. [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest/Introduction/Intro.html) have a sample. Here is a tutorial:[Easy AAC compressed audio conversion on iOS](http://atastypixel.com/blog/easy-aac-compressed-audio-conversion-on-ios/)

Comment: @CaptJak thanks for the answer.
if you could put is as an answer that will be great!

also do you know how to cut out certain portion of the music ? i.e this music is 3minutes long but i just need the 30sec only

Comment: I added the answer. For the other question, I think it might be wise to post it as different question. I don't remember exactly how it's done, and if someone else can answer the question before I can remember, it would be easier to find if it was on it's own. And it would be good to add some more detail (i.e. do you need the first 30 seconds, or out of the middle somewhere? Are you trying to do something like the iTunes song preview?)

Comment: I answered your [other question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328299/how-to-trim-or-crop-music-from-itunes-library/18347949#18347949)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to convert your audio files is by using the EXTAudioFileConvert API from Apple.

Tutorial on using the EXTAudioFileConvert can be found at: [Easy AAC compressed audio conversion on iOS](http://atastypixel.com/blog/easy-aac-compressed-audio-conversion-on-ios/).

Comment: do you know of other api that will convert it easily ? iOS 7 seen to breaks the code