# how to trim or crop music from itunes library

Tags: ios, core-audio

i would like to grab music from user's library for audio music fingering. what i required are just 30 sec of each songs. how do i go about it ? i do not need to save the audio but just using it.

[iOS Audio Trimming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698787/ios-audio-trimming)

[Trim audio with iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238219/trim-audio-with-ios)

are the above 2 links the way to go ?

thanks for reading and appreciated any comments.

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the music that a user already has in his device library, you would use the [MPMediaItemCollection class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaItemCollection_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html). Sample code on using this (although slightly old and not using ARC) can also be found in the Apple Docs in the ["Add Music"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008845) sample.

I am not sure what Audio Player you are using, but if you would like to seek to a particular point in a song or audio file, you can do so by using the `currentTime` property in the AVAudioPlayer class, [(noted in the Apple Docs)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/currentTime).

To implement this, you would do something as simple as:

```
yourAudioPlayer.currentTime = 60;
```

This will jump the song to the 1 minute mark. I am not 100% sure on how to do this before the song plays, but I would put it in the Play IBAction, before it starts playing:

```
- (IBAction) playOrPause: (id) sender {

    if (self.player.playing) {

        [self.button setTitle: @"Play" forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [self.button setTitle: @"Play" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.player pause];

    } else {
        [self.button setTitle: @"Pause" forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [self.button setTitle: @"Pause" forState: UIControlStateNormal];

        [self.player.currentTime = 60];  //Set the seeker here

        [self.player play];
    }

}
```

To stop the playback after a certain amount of time (you say 30 sec) you could use an NSTimer that will call `stop` on the player after a 30 second delay. Something like:

```
    [NSTimer 
     scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0
     target:self.player
     selector:@selector(stop)
     userInfo:nil
     repeats:NO];
```

If you put that in the IBAction that you use to play, that should do it!